# Expand Relationships in Pocketbase

Tags: pocketbase

Pocketbase seems to support `expand` field to expand relationships when viewing or listing records. I am not sure if I am using it right but here's my setup:

- galleries (has many sections)
- sections (belongs to one gallery) (has gallery_id relation field)

This is how I tried viewing the gallery record with sections expanded in the response:

```
  const pb = new PocketBase("http://127.0.0.1:8090/");
  const data = await pb.records.getOne(
    "galleries",
    context.params!.id as string,
    {
      page: 1,
      perPage: 100,
      expand: "sections,sections.galleryId, sections.gallery, gallery.sections",
    }
  );
```

None of these worked. @expand field still comes empty. Am I using this correctly or is expand suppose to work on the reverse relationship. Like it would expand a gallery inside a section but not vice versa??

Comment: Which version of the dart-sdk and pocketbase are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pocketbase just added indirect expand in v0.8 - here's the docs on how to do it.

https://pocketbase.io/docs/expanding-relations/#indirect-expand

my expand became `sections(gallery).photos(section)` - this fetched the gallery and expanded its sections and its sections photos.